# How can I specific only one filter for a specific request?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I am using `JAX-RX` specification to build web service using java.
And I am using Filter for authentication and authorization purpose,
`JAX-RS` call all filter for each request and i don't need that
I need to specific only one filter for a certain request
How can i do that ?
I only want prevent another filter to call.
I don't use `web.xml`, I am using `RootClass` extend `Application` Class with `@ApplicationPath` annotation like this :

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class RootEndPoint extends Application {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
This is my quastion and
I will answer it for anyone will need it in future.
if you want to prevent some filter you can use @NameBinding Annotation by do this steps :

Assume that we have two filter : `ManagerUserFilter` and `NormalUser`
and I want to login as manager and i don't want `NormalUserFilter` get called
follow these steps :

1- create Annotation and use these annotation with it :

```
@NameBinding
@Target({TYPE,METHOD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ManagerFilterResources {}
```

2- use this annotation in `ManagerUserFilter` Like that :

```
@Provider
@ManagerFilterResources
public class ManagerUserFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter,ContainerResponseFilter {
// implementation abstract method in Containers
}
```

3 - use this annotation in `ManagerResource` class like this

```
@ManagerFilterResources
@Path("/manager")
public class ManagerResource {
```

Note : you can use this annotation on method also if you want apply filter on only one method.

4 - create another annotation for `NormalUserFilter` like first step and name it NormalUser as example, and use it in NormalUserFilter like that :

```
@NameBinding
@Target({TYPE,METHOD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NormalUser {}
```

and use it in filter

```
@Provider
@NormalUser
public class NormalUserFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

// implementation abstract method in Containers
```

if you go to `/manager` url NormalUserFilter will not get called
I hope this answer will be usefull.